# "PHP Error was Encountered" Error in codeigniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter

I get the following errors while trying to view my create new user page.

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: list
Filename: views/rtc.php
Line Number: 33

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: views/rtc.php
Line Number: 33

I get these errors while trying to run my create new user file, where I am trying to create a dynamic drop down list. Below is my 
view>rtc.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/common.js"></script>
    <div class="contentform">        

        <fieldset style="width:55%;float:left;margin-left:5%;">
            <legend >New RTC</legend>

        <!--FORM STARTS HERE-->

        <form action="<?= site_url('form/rtc_insert'); ?>" method="post">   

            <label >RTC ID:<span id="rtc_reg_id_re" style="font-size:12px;float:right;"></span></label>
            <input type="text" name="id" id="rtc_reg_id" placeholder="RTC ID" required/>                 
            <label >Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="Name" required/>
                <label >Country:</label>
                   <select name="country" >
                       <option>Select Country</option>
                        <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
                        <option value="India">India</option>
                        <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
                        <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
                        </select><br/><br/>                                
            <?php
            if($list->num_rows > 0){
                ?>
                <label >Dzongkhag:</label>
                <select onchange="selectGeog(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
                    <option value="-1">Select Dzongkhag</option>
            <?php foreach($list->result() as $listElement){ ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $listElement->id?>"><?php echo $listElement->dz_name?></option>
            <?php
                    }
                ?> 

                 <label >Geog:</label>
                <select id="geog_dropdown" onchange="selectVillage(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
                    <option value="-1">Select geog</option>
                </select>
                <span id="geog_loader"></span>

                <label >Village:</label>
                <select id="village_dropdown">
                    <option value="-1">Select village</option>
                </select>
                <span id="village_loader"></span>

                <label >Address:</label>
                <textarea type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address" required/></textarea>                       
                <input type="submit" value="Save" id="rtc_reg_submit" class="button"><br/>
             <?php
            }else{
                echo 'No Country Name Found';
            }
            ?>
                </form>
```

Here is my controller>form.php

```
    function rtc_insert()   
    {

        $session_user=$this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        if($session_user['ath']=='admin')
        {$msg = $this->drop_model->getDzongkhag();
            redirect('form/rtc/You Have Successfully Created '.$msg);

        }
        else
            {
            echo ' <script type="text/javascript">
                        alert("Access Error....");
                        </script>';
                redirect('login/home');
            }

    }
public function dropDown()
    {
        $this->load->model('drop_model');
        $result['list']=$this->model->getDzongkhag();
        $this->load->view('rtc',$result);
        }

    public function loadData()
    {
        $loadType=$_POST['loadType'];
        $loadId=$_POST['loadId'];

        $this->load->model('drop_modelmodel');
        $result=$this->model->getData($loadType,$loadId);
        $HTML="";

        if($result->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach($result->result() as $list){
                $HTML.="<option value='".$list->id."'>".$list->name."</option>";
            }
        }
        echo $HTML;
    }
```

and the model>drop_model.php

```
    <?php
class drop_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function getDzongkhag(){
        $this->db->select('id,dz_name');
        $this->db->from('dzongkhag');
        $this->db->order_by('dz_name', 'asc'); 
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query; 
    }

    function getData($loadType,$loadId){
        if($loadType=="geog"){
            $fieldList='gid,g_name as name';
            $table='geog';
            $fieldName='dz_id';
            $orderByField='g_name';                     
        }else{
            $fieldList='vid,village_name as name';
            $table='village';
            $fieldName='geog_id';
            $orderByField='village_name';   
        }

        $this->db->select($fieldList);
        $this->db->from($table);
        $this->db->where($fieldName, $loadId);
        $this->db->order_by($orderByField, 'asc');
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query; 
    }
}
?>
```

Everything was running fine, problem started after I added the codes for the dynamic drop down list in my form which I learned from a tutorial! Any help will be welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

the error is in the line `if(list->num_rows > 0)` should be `if($list->num_rows() > 0)`

Comment: The error still remains @vickel, I changed  the code as you have told. Thanks

Comment: in controller type: print_r($result['list']), what does it say?

Comment: you also have an error here:  if($list->num_rows > 0) should be if($list->num_rows() > 0), maybe this is line 33?

Comment: I dont get any thing when typing print_r($result['list']); maybe i typed it in the wrong place.

Comment: `if($list->num_rows > 0);` You are right this is line 33, I changed it to what you said, The error went away but got another error `Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\application\views\rtc.php on line 33` and `
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: list
Filename: views/rtc.php
Line Number: 33` still remains.

Comment: now you have to check, whats wrong with your database query, as you get NULL back

Comment: sorry I think I made a mistake, put your code back as it was and only change if($list->num_rows() > 0)

Comment: somewhere something has gone terribly wrong, its not working, thanks for the help vickel

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this from controller>form.php:

```
redirect('form/rtc/You Have Successfully Created '.$msg);
```

I do suggest to use [Flashdata](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) when flashing successful or fail message.